# webpack + typescript + lodash

Tags: typescript, webpack, lodash

I am trying set up the webpack with typescript and lodash but when I run webpack to build the bundle I get the error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lodash' in ....

I am importing loadas as: import * as _ from 'lodash'.

This is the package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/flux": "^3.1.4",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.91",
    "@types/lodash-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.0.29",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.3",
    "@types/react-router": "^4.0.19",
    .....
    ..... 
    "ts-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "tslint": "^5.8.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "tslint-react": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "flux": "^3.1.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0"
  }
```

This is the part of webpack.config.js related with ts:

```
resolve: {
    // Automatically resolve certain extensions in this case js and jsx.
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx']
},
.....
.....
{
     test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/, // The Condition must match
     exclude: /node_modules/, // The Condition must NOT match
     loader: 'ts-loader'
},
```

And this is the tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "noLib": false,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
    },
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I can't see any obvious reason why `import * as _ from 'lodash'` would not work unless the dependency is not installed. Issue an `npm install` in the project root just to make sure all the dependencies are indeed installed.

Comment: Thank a lot man, I run npm install again and now working.